# Django email logging isn't sending emails

Tags: django

I've implemented logging within my settings file, but no emails are being sent when a 500 error is hit. I'm on django 3.x

All of the email settings within my settings file work. These settings are successfully used to deliver account confirmation emails, for example.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@########'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#######'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@######'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'support@########'
EMAIL_PORT = #####
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'                
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you set less-secured access on your gmail portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the admin email was different than the one I had setup on my email settings. The notifications were going out, just to a different account.